# Are font-extensions registered in JVM fonts?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying font-extensions for my *JasperReports* reports. Most of the reports are working fine
but some specific reports are giving this exception:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'ArialBD' is not available to the JVM.
```

The *ArialBD* font is bundled in my font-extensions jar and its proper mapping is defined as well. Then why this error is coming? I also have another confusion, when we are using font-extensions, are these fonts registered in the JVM? Like they are physically present in the jre/lib/font folder. Can someone clarify this confusion.

Comment: Did you add the *jar* to classpath?

Comment: Yes, it has been present on the classpath. Additionally other fonts defined in the font-extensions are working fine except this one. Are font-extensions registered on JVM?